# I used to manually add the jars I needed in a java project on eclipse. What should I do instead?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I used to manually add the jars I needed in a java project on eclipse.

I am trying to set up my java project in Eclipse for the use of `Tess4J`. Instead of adding the jars, I could use maven dependency right? If so, how? I have tried to take a look but I am confused honestly. If you have a guide I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Use maven. Eclipse has maven integration. Good luck! https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html

Comment: Or use Gradle ;-) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_dependency_management.htm

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so I should make my Java project a Maven Project?

Comment: @LMC I am definitely more familiar with gradle since I use it in Android Studio.